# Getting ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

When I run this code I am getting an error. I am a newbie. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import pandas as pd
df_percentage = (pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep=';'))
print(df_percentage)
x=df_percentage.Percentage
y=df_percentage.Peakintensity
x = x.reshape(-1,1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
m1 = model.fit(x_train,y_train)

print(m1)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
print ('Coefficients: ', model.coef_)
print ('Intercept: ',model.intercept_)
```

Comment: Could you add more information about where do you get the error?

Comment: In the part of printing m1 I am getting error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: My x data is 40, 60, 70, 90 in series. And y data is 6220, 7208, 7926, 10512. Its also in series not a list

Comment: @LinFelix Error is ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Comment: @BenJack are you sure you are not getting the error at line: `y_pred = model.predict(x_test)` or `m1 = model.fit(x_train,y_train)` ?

Comment: @overmach sorry I am getting error before. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'. Did you mean: 'shape'? : this error is coming when i use this code x = x.reshape(-1,1)

Comment: @overmach And if i don't use that statement(x = x.reshape(-1,1)) this is coming 'Error is ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead'

Comment: try 

'''x = x.values.reshape(-1,1)'''

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.reshape.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = x.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

will fix it.

see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.reshape.html

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Now I would like to know how can I predict the values for the x with this model?

Comment: After estimating intercept and coefficient, you can use the model formulation of linear regression. In this case simply: intercept + x*coefficient = y

Comment: eg for x = 100:

intercept + 100 * coefficient = y

with intercept = 2422.000000000002 and coefficient = 87.75789474 this would roughly mean: 2422 + 87.76 * 100 = 11198

Comment: you can use your trained model in python to do the same:

model.predict([[100]])

Comment: you can compare your "y_pred" variable with "y_test" to see how well it performed on your test data

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. If  I want to predict x values by giving the y values, what do I have to change?

Comment: Create a new model exactly as you did before. But this time, instead set x and y like that:

x=df_percentage.Peakintensity
y=df_percentage.Percentage

Now the model will predict Percentage based on Peakintensity. 


You can, however, also rearrange the equation I posted before and do:


(y-intercept)/coefficient = x